# I have two divs that both have their margins set to 0 but there is a space between them

Tags: html, css

I'm working at learning css and webdesign and I'm trying to get the basics of how a simple website is organized.

Ideally I would like there to be no space between the main navigation and the main content. Unfortunately, there is a space between them that appearantly even setting both div's margins to 0 won't fix (I originally thought it was just the margins collasping).

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#main-nav {
  height: 37px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#main-content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

p {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav">
  <p>This is just a demonstration of my problem.</p>
</div>
<div id="main-content">
  <p>This is just a demonstration of my problem.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a space because of p element tag. Browsers set default margin and padding to all the elements. You could add HTML reset to your code to avoid it.

You can check it out - [HTML5 Reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)

Here is your modified code without the reset.

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#main-nav {
    height: 37px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#main-content {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
p {
    color: lime;
    margin:0
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav">
    <p>This is just a demonstration of my problem.</p>
</div>
<div id="main-content">
    <p>This is just a demonstration of my problem.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helps. If I may ask though, why does the p element tag do this? The p is in a containing div, how do those margins interact outside of them?

Comment: Not only p element, browsers have default values for many elements like h1,h2,p. That's why we always need html reset to reset the default values set by browsers.

Comment: It interact outside because margin is set outside and padding is set inside of element.

Comment: But the p element is inside of the div element; shouldn't the margin create space outside of the p element, inside of the div element?

Comment: Yes, it will do like this only but you haven't added overflow hidden to your next div element and because of lack of HTML reset the p tag in next div element has default margin-top value and it was create space between both the divs..

Answer (score 0):

Follow this **CSS** code

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

body {
   background-color: black;
}

#main-nav {
  height: 37px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
}

 #main-content {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
 }

 p {
  color: lime;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
.main-nav p,
.main-content {
    margin:0;
}
```